# How to save user forum screen as a picture in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, image, screenshot

I'm looking for code to save a screen of user forum in Excel VBA as an image (a code similar to (ctrl + print screen) in keyboard). In this user forum, I have some results I just want to save the screen as an image to send it by mail. I made a button. If I click this button, I want to make screenshot of user forum and save it as an image in a path in PC.

Comment: What did you try by your own? What research you did in order to find a solution, or something helpful?

Answer (score 2):

Try the next way, please:

1. Copy the next API function on tot of a standard module (in the declaration area):

```
Option Explicit

'for print screen
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal _
                     bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As LongPtr)

Private Const VK_SNAPSHOT = &H2C
```

2. In the same module, copy the next code and run it:

```
Sub PrintScreen()
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 1, 0, 0

    ActiveSheet.Paste
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(ActiveSheet.Shapes.count)
        .top = Range("A1").top
        .left = Range("A1").left
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: i make a button to save the screen of user forum i want if i click on this button it make screenshot and save it in a path as an image